# Why am I getting an error here?

Tags: php

Just trying to go along with some tutorials! CAn't figure out why I'm getting an error on the form action line

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['Username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (!empty($Username)&&!empty($password)) {
        echo 'OK';  
        } else {
            echo 'You must supply an email and a password.';
        }
    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
     Email: <input type="text" name="username"> Password: <input type="password" name="password">
     <input type ="submit" value = "Log In"  />

     </form>
```

Comment: you are missing `}` at the end of your PHP code

Comment: Where's the end of the first `if`?

Comment: Never say what the error is you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (!empty($Username)&&!empty($password)) {
```

you have 2 variables $username and $Username - should be the same?

Comment: Good catch, btw; PHP's variable names [ARE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) case-sensitive. But I wonder is that the only error in that code...

Comment: @raina77ow - i think he didn't post all of the code.. so hard to tell..

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your initial if condition block

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because **$current_file** is not defined? Or are you defining it before on your code?

Comment: I'm including this page in another page so that should take care of that right?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't catch the **if** missing the closing curly brace, that's where the error is, unless you have code below where you close it.